# React Native ScrollView Ref for controll scrollEnabled Props

Tags: react-native

How to change `scrollEnabled` Props of ScrollView in React Native with `ref` of ScrollView.

For example:

```
<ScrollView
   scrollEnabled={}  //<-- change this value from ref of this ScrollView
>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can change state/props from a reference to a component. You can put state as boolean value for scrollEnabled. Now you can enable/disable scroll by changing the state.

```
function toggleScrollView() {
   let isScrollEnabled = !this.state.isScrollEnabled;
   this.setState({isScrollEnabled});
}

<ScrollView
   scrollEnabled={this.state.isScrollEnabled}
>
```